# storing millions of files in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, disk-usage, database, disk-management

i have about a few millions text files that needs to be stored in one single directory, under a few thousands sub-directories. roughly, it's about a few thousands text files for one single folder, and there is a few thousands, maybe hundred thousands that kind of folders.

now i come across the point that `No space left in device`; my question is: given sufficient spaces, how can i store that much data inside a computer like personal laptop, without facing inode problem?

Comment: "without facing inode problem" What problem do you suspect you will face?

Answer (score 2):

Read the man page for mkfs.ext4, and using the -i, -I, and -N arguments, set up the filesystem with the inodes it needs to meet your needs.  In a terminal, either
 `man mkfs.ext4`
 for a terminal display or
 `xman mkfs.ext4`
for a GUI display

Comment: Be aware that `mkfs.ext4` (or `mkfs.anything`) will effectively erase all data on the given partition!  If you don't already have an unused partition on the drive, you'll have to do some more gymnastics with `gparted` or a similar tool.  This will have to be done from a boot disk.